# The graph token has no scopes, while trying to get Azure functions working with Excel output

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to get Azure Functions working with IoT Hub messages, and on message adding a row to an Excel file.

I tried with setting Excel integration as output, which wasn't working, so I changed and tried with Excel input.

When I try this, I get the following failure in the console.

> The graph token has no scopes. Ensure your application is properly configured to access the Microsoft Graph.

What is the correct way to get the credentials working with my Microsoft account? Note that I'm trying to connect with my account and not end-user's account, which is mentioned in all the tutorials/documentation.

I'm using a personal Microsoft account and not Org account, in case that is important.

Here is my `function.json`.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "IoTHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "samples-workitems",
      "connection": "home-auto_events_IOTHUB",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    {
      "type": "excel",
      "name": "inputTable",
      "path": "Documents/Test.xlsx",
      "worksheetName": "Sheet1",
      "tableName": "Table1",
      "identity": "ClientCredentials",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the default `index.js` from the template.

```
module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array: ${IoTHubMessages}`);

    IoTHubMessages.forEach(message => {
        context.log(`Processed message: ${message}`);
    });

    context.done();
};
```

Questions:

- What else can I try to get the authentication working? Any ideas on what is going wrong? I'm not even sure if I'm using this correctly.
- How to debug this? I can't seem to figure out how to get any more information on the failure then what is shown in the web console.

Comment: Based on the error message, you didn't add https://graph.microsoft.com to your scope. How did you deal with the authentication? If you can provide more details, we can help you further.

Comment: I did configure AAD from the portal itself while adding the bonding. From what I understand, it added the scope and I can see that in Authorization/Authentication section. I have also granted admin permissions for the required scopes and permissions.

Comment: You are using personal account, so you should use azure ad v2.0 endpoint. Did you add scopes when you request an access token. Something like 
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };

Comment: Can you provide the document which you referred to?

Comment: This is what I did. I created a new function with HTTP trigger, added new integration in Input for Excel. There "Configure AAD now", then go to "Manage -> AAD -> Manage permissions -> Grant permissions". Set Identity to "Client credentials" from integration.
I know this looks naive, but I really can't figure out what else can I do there. I could make the calls directly from the function, but I think it'd be easier to use the integration, if it works!?

Comment: Also, I don't know where else I can define the scope. Though, the AD authentication page, the permissions shows up and shows count for Delegated permissions. Application permissions there shows zero, don't know if that matters or how to grant those, if I need to.

Comment: I haven't followed any one document, unfortunately, mainly because I couldn't find a nice one.

Comment: I think that was the cause. You need to grant application permissions to your application and click grant permissions. Click Manage Permissions->click Add->click Select an API->choose Microsoft Graph(or other api you need)->You will find the application permissions, choose the permissions you need->click done->click Grant permissions.

Comment: I cannot select Microsoft Graph from Add -> Select an API. It is disabled. Also, I already have "Read user files" selected in Delegate permissions. What else do I require?

Comment: Delegated permissions - Are used by apps that have a signed-in user present. Application permissions - Are used by apps that run without a signed-in user present; Do you have a signed-in user?

Comment: Nope. But I cannot see direct equivalent of "Read user files" in App permissions. I tried allowing "Read files in all site collections", but no luck.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It is the same error as before, "The graph token has no scopes"

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;

The workaround is to generate the tokens on your own and then make the rest subscription call to the graph api from your Azure Function.

---

Most probably the token you're acquiring does not contain a `scp` claim but `roles` instead.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  ...
  "alg": "RS256",
  ...
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  ...
  "app_displayname": "change notification app",
  ...
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  ...
  "ver": "1.0",
  ...
}.[Signature]
```

please take a look at what the Webhook Azure Function binding is expecting from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/blob/master/src/MicrosoftGraphBinding/Config/GraphServiceClientManager.cs#L57)

There are other users facing the same issue as you can see from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/issues/95) too, 
what makes me think this extension could be outdated/under-development.